# Pipe libvips CLI output to stdout in Windows

Tags: stdout, image-conversion, vips, heic

I am using the Windows `libvips` CLI to convert images from `HEIC` to `PNG` format. I want to pipe the converted output to another process without writing to disk. This can be achieved by writing to `stdout` (i.e. typing only the file extension as output file):

```
vips copy input.heic .png
```

However, if I write to a file instead:

```
vips copy input.heic output.png
```

and compare the `stdout` byte stream to the contents of `output.png`, they are somewhat different. Indeed, writing `stdout` to a file results in a corrupted PNG.

Further analysis made me realise that the difference between `stdout` and `output.png` is a large number of randomly placed `CR` characters in `stdout` that are not present in the file. Everything else is identical.

Is there any way to get the right byte stream in `stdout` as it was read from `output.png`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you've hit a bug --- Windows creates stdin and stdout in text mode, so when libvips writes to stdout, any newline characters will be automatically expanded to newline + carriage return.

When running on win, libvips probably needs to call `_setmode(1, O_BINARY);` to force binary mode before writing image data. I've pushed a patch to libvips 8.10 and credited you. This fix will be in 8.10.3, due in a week or two.

Comment: You are totally right. I have searched the byte stream for `LF` and there is always a `CR` preceding. As a temporary patch I have replaced all those `CRLF` with `LF` and now the byte stream matches the `output.png` read. Thanks!

Comment: You could also use something like python -- you can write a 5 line program to open a file descriptor in binary mode and write to that, It would be safer than changing all cr-lf pairs. Sample code here: https://libvips.github.io/libvips/2019/11/29/True-streaming-for-libvips.html